# MonoTouch: Calling UIWebView.LoadHTMLString Once Web Page is Loaded

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios

When a UIWebView contains an external web site using LoadRequest, then the LoadHtmlString() is called, you get this error. Is there a way around this?

```
0   OilGasDictionary                    0x000908ec mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   OilGasDictionary                    0x00005c42 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 178
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9555059b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   OilGasDictionary                    0x00169eee mono_runtime_invoke + 126
5   OilGasDictionary                    0x0020c14d monotouch_exception_handler + 61
6   CoreFoundation                      0x011c112c __handleUncaughtException + 76
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0359ef43 _objc_terminate + 86
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0437d8de _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 13
9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0437d946 __cxa_bad_typeid + 0
10  libc++abi.dylib                     0x0437eb3e __cxa_current_exception_type + 0
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0359ee49 objc_exception_rethrow + 47
12  CoreFoundation                      0x010f7e10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 304
13  CoreFoundation                      0x010f7ccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
14  WebCore                             0x07395220 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 560
15  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x954f8ed9 _pthread_start + 335
16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x954fc6de thread_start + 34
```

Comment: Can you supply a small sample ? because the code I wrote is working (so I likely did something different :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without seeing some sample code but since `UIWebView.LoadRequest` is not [reentrant](http://double-slash.net/category/code-snippets/) you should take care to ensure `LoadHtmlString`is not called until the request has finished loading (they likely share some logic and potentially the same limitation).

My own sample did that (instinctively since I learned the reentrancy limitation recently) and works without any issue.