# MonoTouch UIWebView.LoadHtmlString randomly fails on device

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I have `UIWebView` in a cell of a table. I am calling `UIWebView.LoadHtmlString` and it is working fine in simluator but randomly crashes on a device with the following stacktrace.

```
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at EP.TapTeam.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /projects/tapteam/trunk/iOS/EP.TapTeam.UI/Main.cs:17
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

Thread started: 
 0   TapTeam                             0x01eb1d79 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 244
 1   TapTeam                             0x01e9e429 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 172
 2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3669472f _sigtramp + 42
 3   UIKit                               0x32e452e9 -[UIWebView webView:didCommitLoadForFrame:] + 48
 4   UIKit                               0x32e445a7 -[UIWebViewWebViewDelegate webView:didCommitLoadForFrame:] + 22
 5   CoreFoundation                      0x3310d7a4 __invoking___ + 68
 6   CoreFoundation                      0x3308543d -[NSInvocation invoke] + 108
 7   CoreFoundation                      0x330850d9 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 36
 8   WebKit                              0x3328f7bd -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 408
 9   CoreFoundation                      0x3310d68d ___forwarding___ + 576
 10  CoreFoundation                      0x33084180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
 11  CoreFoundation                      0x3310d7a4 __invoking___ + 68
 12  CoreFoundation                      0x3308543d -[NSInvocation invoke] + 108
 13  WebCore                             0x3210ec3d _ZL11SendMessageP12NSInvocation + 16
 14  WebCore                             0x321b1adf _ZL20HandleDelegateSourcePv + 66
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x330e1a79 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x330e375f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 382
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x330e44eb __CFRunLoopRun + 230
 18  CoreFoundation                      0x33074ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
 19  CoreFoundation                      0x33074dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
 20  GraphicsServices                    0x35f3f41f GSEventRunModal + 114
 21  GraphicsServices                    0x35f3f4cb GSEventRun + 62
 22  UIKit                               0x32c91d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
 23  UIKit                               0x32c8f807 UIApplicationMain + 670
 24  TapTeam                             0x000fe5b8 wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 240
 25  TapTeam                             0x01de3568 EP_TapTeam_Application_Main_string__ + 152
 26  TapTeam                             0x003f3b74 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
 27  TapTeam                             0x01e9fc07 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1054
 28  TapTeam                             0x01f1a993 mono_runtime_invoke + 90
 29  TapTeam                             0x01f1d7eb mono_runtime_exec_main + 306
 30  TapTeam                             0x01f1da3f mono_runtime_run_main + 482
 31  TapTeam                             0x01ea472b mono_jit_exec + 94
 32  TapTeam                             0x01f70b84 main + 2224
 33  TapTeam                             0x00018fc0 start + 40
```

The only workaround I found is to call LoadHtmlString with a 1 second delay:

```
        NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(1f, () => {
            contentWebView.LoadHtmlString(someInfo, null);
        });
```

I am wondering is there a true solution?

Update, the code that I am using:

```
public class OverviewControllerTableSource: UITableViewSource
{

public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellIdentifier) as OverviewCell_text;

        if (cell == null)
        {     
        cell = new OverviewCell_text(_cellIdentifier);  
        }

    return cell.Bind(_tableItems[indexPath.Section].Items[indexPath.Row]);
}

}
```

and Cell

```
public partial class OverviewCell_text : UITableViewCell
{
    public OverviewCell_text (NSString cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("OverviewCell_text", this, null);
            contentWebView.WeakDelegate = new UIWebViewDelegate();
            contentWebView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            contentWebView.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
            cellText.ScrollEnabled = false;
            contentWebView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    }

    public UITableViewCell Bind(string someInfo)
    { 
            // TODO next string without timer randomly crashes on device.
            if(someInfo != null)
            {
                NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(1f, () => {
                        contentWebView.LoadHtmlString(someInfo, null);
                });
        }

            return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see some code to really help you but, since your workaround adds a delay, you should check that you do not re-enter inside `UIWebView` before it's current request is completed.

IWO be aware that `UIWebView` is [not reentrant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9321991/220643) and your additional delay makes it more likely (but not safe) that the request was completed.

Comment: I don't see how your code deal with re-entrancy, i.e. having multiple instances of `UIWebView` (like one per cell) is not a solution. Quote (from the web blog linked to the SO question I linked to) "If you’ve ever tried to put multiple UIWebView objects on screen and load documents into all of them at once, you may have stumbled across an undocumented limitation of the iPhone SDK: the loadRequest method on UIWebView is not re-entrant,"

Comment: Poupou, thanks for you help. I am not sure reentrance issue was the cause but crashes go away after I got rid of Nib and started creating UIWebView programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Make the UIWebView a member of your ViewController class (not an inline variable) for garbage collection purposes.

Comment: I use Nib to load a cell, so UIWebView is a member of the class.

Comment: As a recommendation, its generally bad practice to put a web view directly inside a tableview like that.  I'm guessing you are hitting some kind of garbage collection or re-entrant issue as poupou mentioned.